# Run through multiple folders, find a specific file, copy the contents into another file in python

Tags: python, import

I'm new to python!

I'm trying to write a code in python (version = 3.5) to scan through MULTIPLE folders, find a specific file, open in read mode, copy the data into another master file on the desktop.

In other words, I have 10 folders, each folder has 3 files which are of the same name. I have to open one file and copy the contents into another file and move on to the next folder to find the same file again, copy the contents and append into the master file.

I am successfully able to scan multiple folders, files and print them but opening in read mode and copy to master file is the problem.

I have created a simple UI to browse to a particular location. This can be seen in the code below.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import Scrollbar
import os
from os import path
import sys
import time
import subprocess
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import font
Application = tkinter.Tk()

Application.title("Stride_Activity_Merger")
Application.configure(bg = "CadetBlue3")


Application.geometry("950x650+300+300")

def browse():
    browse.filename = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir=[("All files", "*")])  
    x = 0
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(browse.filename):
        print('--\nroot_%d = ' %x + root)
        x+=1;
        list_file_path = os.path.join(root, 'my-directory-list.txt')

       for filename in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)




            print('\t- file %s (full path: %s)' % (filename, file_path))
            if filename == 'Activity-Table.csv':
                with open('Results_For_Activity-Table.txt', 'w+') as output, open('Activity-Table.csv', 'r') as input:
                    while True:
                        data = input.read(10)
                        if data == '':  # end of file reached
                            break
                        output.write(data)
                        print("File Found!")



B1 = Button(text = "B r o w s e     T o     I n p u t     F o l d e r", font="None", height=8, width=85, bg="light coral", command=browse)
B1.place(x=85, y=260)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(Application)
Application.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what is the problem? do you get an error? if you do please upload the stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for care! 
The problem is I am not able to find the specific file and copy the data into master file.
That happens here:
if filename == 'Activity-Table.csv':
                with open('Results_For_Activity-Table.txt', 'w+') as output, open('Activity-Table.csv', 'r') as input:
                    while True:
                        data = input.read(10)
                        if data == '':  # end of file reached
                            break
                        output.write(data)
                        print("File Found!")
Error: Activity-Table.csv file not found

Comment: Try to give the full path to `open()` and not just the name.

Answer (score 1):

Get the file path after

```
if filename == 'Activity-Table.csv':
```

use

```
with open('Results_For_Activity-Table.txt', 'a') as output
```

this will let you append data to your results file. Use

```
all_input_data = input.read()
```

this will read all the data in the input file no need for the while loop